# FXTRACT instruction example

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

I wrote this code in NASM:

```
section .data
    fvar: dd 123.456
    fsig: dq 0.0
    fexp: dq 0.0

section .text
    fld dword[fVar]
    fxtract          ; put significand in ST(0), and exponent in ST(1)
    fstp qword[fsig] ; fsig = 1.929
    fstp qword[fexp] ; fexp = 6
```

I was waiting to find: `fsig = 123456` and `fexp = -3`.
Or something like:     `fsig = 1.23456` and `fexp = 3`.
So, what Am I missing?

Comment: Note that processors work in binary. `123.45=1.92890625*2^6`.

Comment: @Jester thank's, I changed the value slightly, but I get it anyway

Comment: To get what you want, link to a C standard library and then do `call ftoa` :-) See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632150/turn-float-into-string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962040/easiest-way-to-convert-a-decimal-float-to-bit-representation-manually-based-on-i, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912128/printing-the-integral-part-of-a-floating-point-number

Comment: @Jester Would you like to post that as an answer? Or do you think this question should be closed?

Comment: @CodyGray : `ftoa` is a standard C library function?

Comment: Oh, right. No, it's not defined by the standard. Some libraries have it as an extension. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

`fxtract` gives you the exponent base 2, as @Jester said in the comments.

- 123.456 = 1.929 × 2<sup>6</sup>

To get the exponent base 10, you must know about logarithms.  You calculate the logarithm base 10 of the input, then truncate it to an integer.  In x87, `fldlg2` gives log<sub>10</sub>(x), then `fyl2x` can [calculate the logarithm](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/95cf9088ccb535a1b288a0e651e0a9f116c0f384/lib/libm/arch/i387/e_log10.S#L9) as

- log<sub>10</sub>(x) = log<sub>10</sub>(2) × log<sub>2</sub>(x)

To truncate it to an integer, you set the x87 to round toward zero (by `or`ing 0x0c000 into the control word) and use `frndint`.

To calculate the significand, you divide the input by the power of 10.  The customary way to get a power of 10 is to use powers of 2 and 5, using [integer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101439/3614563) for powers of 5 (as in [David M. Gay's pow5mult](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/95cf9088ccb535a1b288a0e651e0a9f116c0f384/lib/libc/gdtoa/misc.c#L392)), and scaling the floating-point exponent for powers of 2.  A simpler, but perhaps slower or less accurate way, is to use the x87 and the formula

- 10<sup>p</sup> = 2<sup>m</sup> = 2<sup>r</sup> × 2<sup>m - r</sup> where m = log<sub>2</sub>10 × p and r = round(m)

In x87, `fldl2t` provides log<sub>2</sub>(10).  `f2xm1` calculates 2<sup>x</sup> - 1 if x is a fraction between -1 and 1.  `fscale` multiplies by 2<sup>r</sup> if r is an integer.

The code is

```
section .data
    fvar: dd 123.456
    fsig: dq 0.0
    fexp: dq 0.0

section .bss
    newcw: resw 1
    oldcw: resw 1

section .text
global main
main:
    fld dword[fvar]
    ;; fexp = truncate(log_10(fvar))
    fld st0
    fldlg2
    fxch st1            ; st2 = fvar, st1 = log_10(2), st0 = fvar
    fyl2x               ; log_10(fvar) = log_10(2) * log_2(fvar)
    fstcw [oldcw]
    mov dx, [oldcw]
    or  dx, 0x0c000     ; rounding mode = 3, toward zero
    mov [newcw], dx
    fldcw [newcw]
    frndint             ; truncate log_10(fvar)
    fldcw [oldcw]       ; restore old rounding mode
    fst qword[fexp]
    ;; fsig = fvar / 10^(fexp)
    fldl2t              ; st2 = fvar, st1 = fexp, st0 = log_2(10)
    fmulp               ; m = log_2(10) * fexp
    fld st0
    frndint             ; integral part of m
    fxch st1            ; st2 = fvar, st1 = integer, st0 = m
    fsub st0, st1       ; fractional part of m
    f2xm1
    fld1
    faddp               ; 2^(fraction)
    fscale              ; 10^fexp = 2^(integer) * 2^(fraction)
    fstp st1            ; st1 = fvar, st0 = 10^fexp
    fdivp               ; fvar / 10^fexp
    fstp qword[fsig]
    int 3
```

I have added the label `main` and the `int 3` so I can run this in gdb on OpenBSD/amd64.

```
$ nasm -felf64 float10.s && gcc -nopie -o float10 float10.o 
$ gdb float10
...
(gdb) run
...
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
...
(gdb) x/1wf &fvar
0x601000 <fvar>:        123.456001
(gdb) x/1wg &fsig
0x601004 <fsig>:        1.2345600128173828
(gdb) x/1wg &fexp
0x60100c <fexp>:        2
```

Comment: If I try this code (and I did) fvar can't be negative.  It gives NaN on fyl2x. To extend this nice example you should check the sign before taking logarithms.  Anyway nice example.